# How long do direct deposits take to go through?

Tags: banking, deposits

eBay listed the status as "paid" last Friday for some sales I'd made, and that it would be deposited to the bank account I have on file.

It's Monday and I haven't seen any changes in my online banking account.

Does it normally take a few days to process? Are these deposit "delays" dependent on the company depositing it or the bank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Banks don't generally "Post" transactions on Friday-Sunday, meaning any transfers made on those days don't show up until someone processes it on Monday. I would expect the money to show today, and call your bank tomorrow if it doesn't.

Comment: Exactly.  Additionally though, eBay might not pay when they say they do; a lot of places don't.  It might just mean "You're on the queue".  One of my banks also takes 2 days or so for transactions to show up (even though they affect my balance immediately), so you might have to wait as much a 4 business days (2 for eBay, 2 for the bank) for it to show up.

Comment: The comment ended up being the situation; they deposited it this morning.